# How fix: "All sample times must be discrete. No continuous or constant sample times are allowed" on Simulink with "Buffer" block

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

I'm developing a Simulink system in which I get float values at every 0.01 step time. I want to store those data into an array by using the block: "Buffer", if and only if the condition is true.
I set the block: "Rate Transition" with 0.01 step time.

if I set Buffer size=1 into "Buffer" block, it works fine. Whereas if I set the Buffer size=100, it throws this error.

Why does this happen? What's the problem?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQU5i.png)